# prevent z-fighting between billboard particles?

Tags: particles, artifacts

In an effect like blossoming flowers and many other particle effects the z order of individual particles doesn't really matter, so can I tell Blender to make them stop z-fighting and causing flickering and just assign order to each randomly, or some other solution?

Example blend: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/42258

Comment: Isn't giving a bit of Y position variance solving the problem? Could you show a pic of the Z-fighting? In my render test is not visible:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/Tt0aH.jpg

Comment: You wont see flickering caused by z-fighting from a static render, you need to render an animation. It should still be clear if you render at 320x240 to save your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would like to avoid Z-fighting you'll need to give your object at lest a small amount of difference in the location for every axis.

I would suggest to slightly increase the *Velocity* towards the *Normal* direction (e.g from 0 to 0.01) in order to not alter the overall look of the scene substantially, but at the same time, as each particle raise at different time, you'll have a variable distribution of particle location toward the camera.

[image]

Comment: I was about to post the same answer as Carlo. In my tests a particle Velocity on the Normal axis of 0.02 worked really well for me.

Comment: I have upvoted this answer and also want to accept this as an answer but even with those numbers the particles still are visibly moving. While this isn't an issue for my personal problem as I use an orthographic camera I believe for a Q&A site the solution shouldn't be limited to a specific use case. Perhaps if that value could be set to become 0 after nth microseconds after particle birth that would solve it, but I'm not sure the normal of an individual particle can be animated such way.

Comment: Thanks! You are right about that a good answer should be not limited to your current project. think it's just a matter of finding the numbers that would best fit the project (can be 0.001 or even less as long as it looks good with the camera's clipping range and the z-fighting is avoided), but the core of the solution I'm proposing is just "move them with normals". You can left it unaswered as long as you wish, maybe someone else comes with a better idea (I'll be glad to hear that too). Anyway you can always change the accepeted answer.

Comment: Hm, how about a displacement modifier with a very noisy texture on the emitter?

Comment: Yes! That could solve the motion problem definetly. Make an answer with that. Good catch!