# How To Prevent a mesh from overlapping into another?

Tags: animation

What is the best way to prevent this:[image]

Obviously, these are pages in a book, and there are also a stack of pages beneath these, so I've got to make sure there are no "gaps".  Should I utilize adjustments with shrinkwrap, make the pages thicker, add subsurface, etc. or......

Comment: I'd say in this case the best course of action is to *not use* shrinkwrap, and do precisely the opposite. Make sure there's always a small gap between your pages so they are never completely overlapping by for example moving them slightly apart in Z direction, Check this question http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55380/prevent-z-fighting-between-billboard-particles

Comment: Or use the **offset** value or **Keep above surface** options on the shrinkwrap modifier.

Comment: cegaton actually put me on the right track.  While "Keep Above Surface" was not successful, I stumbled on the fact that the "offset" value could be key framed.  Was able to key frame at the right moment to keep meshes from overlapping.  Thanks cegaton...how do I give you a "thumbs up"?

Answer (score 1):

As was pointed out by Duarte Farrajota Ramos , you want to keep the pages separated to avoid Z fighting.

If this causes problems because there are so many pages the separation causes them to have a painfully thick stack, then you might want to start animating the hide_render property (the camera icon in the outliner) so that pages which are obscured don't even get rendered until it's time for them to be visible.

Depending on what fraction of the book you will flip through, you might even have a box-ish mesh representing the bulk of the pages, and then 2-3 flippable pages renderable at any one instant.